Instagram Send message API returns 400 error
When I call instagram send message API,
request:
curl --location 'https://graph.instagram.com/v20.0/{sender_instagram_ID}/messages' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "recipient": {
        "id": {recipient_instagram_ID}
    },
    "message": {
        "text": "hi,"
    }
}'

it always returned the error:
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Cannot find the requested user.",
        "type": "IGApiException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 2534014
    }
}


My App status is developement.
the sender_instagram_ID and recipient_instagram_ID both get from instagram getAccount infoAPI: https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=id,username&access_token=XXX
I have the sender and receipient permission:
"permissions": [
"instagram_business_basic",
"instagram_business_manage_messages",
"instagram_business_content_publish",
"instagram_business_manage_comments"
]
send message API doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-api-with-instagram-login/messaging-api

Anyone can help take a look?
current behavior: receive 400 status code.
expected behavior: send message succeed.

As you mentioned your App status is 'development', do you meant the status in the screenshot from the Meta App Dashboard page?
If so, you will need your app status to be 'Live'. To change the status you will need to enter the Privacy and Terms of Service URL, in 'App Settings' -> 'Basic' on your meta app page.
The good thing is you can put a public url while you're testing and developing your app before sending for review.


my application is live but I have same error
